# Bahdanau Attention

Tags: tensorflow, rnn

In the original paper, the author says that the annotation are the concatenation fo the forward states and the backward states at each time step.

[image]

In the tensorflow [implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/BahdanauAttention) (memory param), the memory field is said to be populated with the output (not hidden state) of an RNN encoder.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in case you havent yet found the answer, tensorflows default attention implementation doesn't perform bi-directional encoding hence you dont see the concatenation (whereas in the paper , its clearly mentioned) ..i am guessing we need to include b-directional rnn's explicitly to mimic the paper. For further proof look at line 788 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py

the comment below the function definition clearly tells you that "*Then it runs an RNN to encode
  embedded encoder_inputs into a state vector. It keeps the outputs of this
  RNN at every step to use for attention later. Next, it embeds decoder_inputs...*"

hope that helped